# Adding CodeableConcept element to FHIR resource 'extension'

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I am new to FHIR and HL7.

I need to add a new element to `ChargeItemDefinition` resource and this element data type is `CodeableConcept`.

I think we need to create a new `StructureDefinition` with a `CodeableConcept` field and then register it on the server and make an extension in `ChargeItemDefinition`.

I tried a tool like Forge to make a custom profile, but creating a new profile or extension is disabled.

But I can't make it after days of trying, does anyone have an example of this or is anyone able to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Forge should perfectly allow you to create a profile based on ChargeItem, if you want to add extensions to that profile. With Forge for FHIR STU3 or R4 (depending on what version you want to use): Open a project folder > New > New Profile > Select Charge Item.

However, without knowing your use case it is hard to judge whether this is what you need. If you share a good description of the use case on chat.fhir.org in the 'implementers' channel people can generally quickly advise you on the best way.

Comment: new profile is disabled in the forge tool i downloaded

Comment: @YousefAlKahky Do you see the "Open profile folder" option? As soon as you choose a folder for your structures, the "New ..." options will light up. I agree this can be confusing when you try Forge for the first time. We will look into making this more clear.

Comment: yes now it works , but how can i add the created profile and extension with my local hapi fhir ? i posted it to structureDefinition rest api and i cannot find it in the listed resources or profiles